# How to write routing.yml when you have more than two query to omit

Tags: symfony

I have routing like this.

```
acme_apiByDate_homepage:
    pattern: /api/byDate/{date}/{page}/{limit}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTopBundle:Api:byDate,date:"",page:0,limit:50, _format: xml  }
```

normal URL is like this

/api/byDate/2013-04-12/0/40

However sometimes I would like to omit the date.

But, this shows error

/api/byDate//0/40

I know I can omit the last parameter, but I want to omit the middle parameter.

How can I make it?

Comment: I would think that common optional variables like page and offset belong in the query string.  Especially for an api.  /api/byDate/date?page=3&limit=100.  Your defaults will still work.  otherwise you will be fighting this problem on many of your routes and life is to short for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change route parameters like that:

```
acme_apiByDate_homepage:
    pattern: /api/byDate/{page}/{limit}/{date}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTopBundle:Api:byDate, page:0, limit:50, date: null, _format: xml }
```

And add in your controller:

```
byDateAction($page, $limit, $date = null)
{
}
```

If null for route and controller doesn't work try an empty string.

**UPDATE**:

You can also define more routes for same action like:

```
api_data_by_date:
    pattern: /api/byDate/{date}/{page}/{limit}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTopBundle:Api:getData, page:0, limit:50, date: null, _format: xml }

api_data_by_page:
    pattern: /api/byPage/{page}/{date}/{limit}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTopBundle:Api:getData, page:0, limit:50, date: null, _format: xml }

api_data_by_limit:
    pattern: /api/byLimit/{limit}/{page}/{date}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTopBundle:Api:getData, page:0, limit:50, date: null, _format: xml }
```

Or, you could add some requirements for parameters, example:

```
api_data_by_date:
    pattern: /api/getData/{date}/{limit}/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTopBundle:Api:getData, page:0, limit:50, date: 2013-04-12, _format: xml }
requirements:
    date:  [0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}
    page:  \d+
    limit: \d+
```

Or try:

```
api_data_by_date:
    pattern: /api-d-{date}-l-{limit}-p-{page}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTopBundle:Api:getData, page:0, limit:50, date: 2013-04-12, _format: xml }
requirements:
    date:  [0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}
    page:  \d+
    limit: \d+
```

Comment: THanks. but is it possible to make page null instead of date. I have a few variables and want to null each depending on situation.

Comment: Thanks I will use first one. Your explanation is quite awesome and big help.

Comment: I'm in a trouble similar to yours. Please visit my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766700/intermediate-route-optional-parameters-in-symfony-2.

Comment: I needed to wrap the date regex in quotes to avoid a circular dependency error.  date: '[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}'