# Intermediate route optional parameters in Symfony 2

Tags: routes, symfony-2.3, optional-parameters

### Problem to solve

Is it possible in Symfony 2, define routes with '*intermediate*' optional parameters. [I'll use other question data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059843/routing-in-symfony2-optional-parameter-en-four-urls-for-one-route), for supporting me using the same style, for example:

- **localhost**/param 1/param 2/param 3/param 4

### Example

- **localhost**/param 1/param 4
- **localhost**/param 2/param 4

Because I have a problem where none of my parameters should be mandatory, and different logics come into play, subordinated to those activated parameters.

Until now if I don't set like this: 
- **localhost**/param 1/param 2/...  
(*missing: **param 3/param 4***)

I can't play with intermediate parameters and it's a less flexible solution.
If previous parameters to optional ones (all of them) aren't specify I can't achieve this.
I don't wan't to create additional routes for the same context if it has a cleaner sight.

This is my route context:

```
zk_time_download_with_all_parameters:
    pattern: /download/{format}/{id}/{start_date}/{end_date}
    defaults: { _controller: ZkTimeBundle:Empleado:download, format: txt, id: %employeeId%, start_date: %start_date%, end_date: %end_date% }
    requirements:
      id: -?\d+
      start_date: ^((\d{4})[/|-]?(\d{2})[/|-]?(\d{2}))*|(\d{2})[/|-]?(\d{2})[/|-]?(\d{4})$
      end_date: ^((\d{4})[/|-]?(\d{2})[/|-]?(\d{2}))*|(\d{2})[/|-]?(\d{2})[/|-]?(\d{4})$
      format: txt|xml|pdf
```

These are the criterias I pursuit:

- Download the data in several *formats*   (*Optional: 'txt' by default*)
- Download data for a specific ***Id*** or whitout it   (*Optional: I peek all I find for the default period: daily or monthly*)
- Specify *start* **OR** *end*, *start* **AND** *end*   (*Optional both dates*)

I check in my controller the route empty parameters and create the corresponding queries (by default).

### Parameters initialized in my Extension class:

```
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    //Route: /marca/{start_date}/{end_date}
    $today = date('d-m-Y');
    $today_object = new \DateTime($today);
    $total_days = $today_object->format('t');

    $month_start = $today_object->format('Y-m-1');
    $month_end = $today_object->format('Y-m-' . $total_days);

    $container->setParameter('month_start', $month_start);
    $container->setParameter('month_end', $month_end);
    $container->setParameter('start_date', $today);
    $container->setParameter('end_date', $today);
    $container->setParameter('format', 'txt');
    $container->setParameter('employeeId', 0);

    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.yml');
}
```

Comment: How do you identify `param (1|2|3|4)`? Can you give concrete examples?

Comment: I'll update my post, for better understanding.